# Reciprocal of a meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F(z)=\displaystyle{\dfrac{1}{z-a}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}(z-a)^{k}}$ be the Laurent series of a meromorphic function with simple pole in $a$ and residue $1$.

Then $G(z):=\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}b_{k}(z-a)^{k}}$ with $b_{1}=1$ and $b_{k+1}:=\displaystyle{\sum_{l=1}^{k}(-1)^{k-l}a_{k-l}b_{l}}$ is such that $F(z)G(z)=1$.

My question is: can one express the convergence radius of the series defining $G(z)$ or at least give conditions to be certain it isn't $0$?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the zero of $F$ closest to $a$ ? (assuming $F$ is meromorphic on a disk around $a$ containing this zero)

Comment: and looking at $\zeta(s)$ before reading a complex analysis course is a very bad idea

Comment: I had a complex analysis course more than 10 years ago, while studying physics.

Comment: You need to prove the Cauchy integral formula, and how $f$ holomorphic on $|z| < R$ is equivalent to $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ on $|z| < R$

Comment: So that $R=\vert a-\rho\vert$, with $\rho$ the closest zero of $F$ to $a$, right? But I meant to express $R$ in terms of the coefficients $a_{k}$, without having to know the location of the zeros.

Comment: you can't (even if of course you can often prove that $R > r$ for some $r$) ${}{}$

Comment: How's that? Using Cauchy's criterion, one should have $R^{-1}=\lim_{k\to\infty}(\vert b_{k}\vert)^{1/k}$, hence it 'remains' to express $b_{k}$ in terms of the $a_{k}$.

Comment: read a complex analysis course